# Virtual hosts with two servers on localhost

Tags: php, windows, zend-framework, vhosts

I have two apache web servers running on my laptop running on windows 7. One on port 80(XAMPP) and the other 81(Zend CE). I use the Zend Server one to develop sites. I want to setup my virtual hosts on the second server using port 81 and not port 80. I have tried but all am getting is a request to search on google.

```
<VirtualHost *:81>
DocumentRoot "C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs"
ServerName localhost:81
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:81>
DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files (x86)/Zend/Apache2/htdocs/folder"
ServerName folder.app
</VirtualHost>
```

I made the changes to the hosts file.

Comment: Drop the port from the `ServerName`

Comment: Would this not be better asked on serverfault?

Comment: @PeeHaa Thx .Have dropped the port from the Servername and its redirecting to xampp on port 80

Comment: @Crisp what is Serverfault

Comment: Same as SO but for server related issues http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

did you remember to edit:

```
NameVirtualHost *:81
```

in the top of your vhosts file?